# Why Bitlocker requires TPM to encrypt boot disk, but not when encrypting other disk?

Tags: bitlocker

I tried encrypting Bitlocker. In some computer I can't do that because the mother board doesn't have tpm.

Yet I can encrypt some drive without TPM.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full disk encryption has many security benefits, but one weakness is a so-called "cold boot" attack.

Taking Truecrypt as an example, the way it normally works when you encrypt a system drive is that when you boot off the drive, Truecrypt asks you for the password.  Without it, you can't boot.

A cold boot attack is where an attacker replaces that bootloader with a malicious one that stores or transmits your boot password.

One thing the TPM can do by the way it works is to make it so that only a specific signed bootloader or OS can boot from the hardware.  This can help prevent someone from replacing the bootloader with a malicious one.

Comment: So it's pretty useless to enscrypt data in a computer that doesn't have TPM because user can simply replace the bootloader there.

Comment: I think Truecrypt lets you boot the bootloader off of a CD-ROM (the recovery disc it makes), so if you are hyper paranoid you could always do that.